# Fabric JS ITEXT Word wrap automatically when control border reach at the end of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabric js ITEXT to write on canvas. When i reach at the end of the canvas text crosses the canvas border which will not show to the user.

I need to wrap the text i have searched but not get any proper solution.

I'm also using fabric.Textbox in place of IText but still got same problem.

Please suggest any solution......

Answer (score 0):

to get word wrapping, you have to override on textbox method.
Look this fiddle for inspiration:

```js
fabric.Textbox.prototype._wrapLine = function(ctx, text, lineIndex) {
    var lineWidth        = 0,
        lines            = [],
        line             = '',
        words            = text.split(' '),
        word             = '',
        letter           = '',
        offset           = 0,
        infix            = ' ',
        wordWidth        = 0,
        infixWidth       = 0,
        letterWidth      = 0,
        largestWordWidth = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        word = words[i];
        wordWidth = this._measureText(ctx, word, lineIndex, offset);
        lineWidth += infixWidth;

        // Break Words if wordWidth is greater than textbox width
        if (this.breakWords && wordWidth > this.width) {
            line += infix;
            var wordLetters = word.split('');
            while (wordLetters.length) {
                letterWidth = this._getWidthOfChar(ctx, wordLetters[0], lineIndex, offset);
                if (lineWidth + letterWidth > this.width) {
                    lines.push(line);
                    line = '';
                    lineWidth = 0;
                }
                line += wordLetters.shift();
                offset++;
                lineWidth += letterWidth;
            }
            word = '';
        } else {
            lineWidth += wordWidth;
        }

        if (lineWidth >= this.width && line !== '') {
            lines.push(line);
            line = '';
            lineWidth = wordWidth;
        }

        if (line !== '' || i === 1) {
            line += infix;
        }
        line += word;
        offset += word.length;
        infixWidth = this._measureText(ctx, infix, lineIndex, offset);
        offset++;

        // keep track of largest word
        if (wordWidth > largestWordWidth && !this.breakWords) {
            largestWordWidth = wordWidth;
        }
    }

    i && lines.push(line);

    if (largestWordWidth > this.dynamicMinWidth) {
        this.dynamicMinWidth = largestWordWidth;
    }

    return lines;
}

var longText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida consequat porta. Nullam euismod, justo interdum iaculis sodales, justo velit sodales lacus, ultrices eleifend metus mauris ut diam. Fusce imperdiet felis porta, viverra nisl id, rutrum ligula. Aliquam consequat, ante ac maximus fringilla, enim metus facilisis dui, nec cursus lacus augue ut risus. Suspendisse felis felis, placerat a suscipit vel, blandit sed lorem. Nullam laoreet, lorem vitae tempus vulputate, ex sapien porta mi, et dictum ante ex at ipsum. Phasellus semper volutpat felis in congue. Nunc aliquam sapien eu fringilla sodales. Quisque ut feugiat sem, sed vehicula justo. Mauris vitae suscipit nisi, sed pulvinar justo. Aenean non tempus nisi. Ut suscipit euismod faucibus. Donec venenatis, justo eget posuere fermentum, lorem nisl pharetra eros, sed convallis enim odio eget ligula. Suspendisse in semper magna. Nullam id sapien faucibus, congue odio quis, porttitor augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed malesuada maximus interdum. Nunc urna urna, dignissim non erat sed, maximus cursus arcu. Praesent tempor erat eu tellus bibendum malesuada. Vivamus est lacus, suscipit ultricies nisl vel, finibus porttitor elit. Nullam at elit sed massa maximus finibus. Morbi pulvinar lectus non ligula vehicula convallis. Praesent ultricies tellus congue eros lobortis, a scelerisque nisi pretium. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet ante, non malesuada metus varius et. Morbi laoreet velit ut auctor pulvinar. Curabitur dignissim elementum libero, finibus scelerisque velit tempor in. In eget consectetur nibh.';

var canvas = fabric.Canvas('c');
var breakingTextbox = new fabric.Textbox(longText, {
        width: 300,
        breakWords: true
});
canvas.add(breakingTextBox);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have used your code it works fine but only an issue the cursor is pointing at the end of text when we click their we use space to point their.   Any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: How to manage the height of object it goes beyond the border of canvas?

Comment: This code works fine but it has an issue related to the position of cursor sometimes it shows at wrong place did you resolve that issue?

Comment: i did not notice this defect. did you make a fiddle somewhere?

Comment: Hello AndreaBogazzi did you check my code i got the cursor position problem when text wrap it shows on wrong position not at the end of the text.

Comment: i checked it. is so big i have to do a slimmed down version to understand it.